# Model Attribute calling error Rails 2.3.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have got an existing Rails project (Rails 2.3.8) and I got following Model with following attribute:

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base

  def name
    read_attribute(:name).nil? ? 'default name' : self.name
  end

end
```

I guessed the original author is trying to return a default value for name as `default name` in this code. But the problem is I have my code trying to access the name attribute:

```
school = School.find(1)

school.name
```

and I'm getting this error:

```
stack level too deep
```

I guess it's because it's calling the name method recursively. Can someone guide me on a workaround for this. Since this had many authors, I'm not sure where they have used the above method. And the system doesnt have any test suit either. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
def name
  read_attribute(:name).nil? ? 'default name' : read_attribute(:name)
end
```

Or more concisely

```
def name
  read_attribute(:name) || 'default name'
end
```